# Trouble with bootstrap 2.3 modal and autocomplete

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

I am using bootstrap 2.3 to build my site and an autocomplete jquery to get data from the database and suggest options to user in a textbox. I am having trouble with the right version for jquery to run both the modal of bootstrap and [autocomplete jquery plugin][1].

If i have jquery 1.1, bootstrap modal works perfectly but autocomplete plugin wont work giving me the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opera' of undefined`

On the other hand if i use jquery version above 1.1, autocomplete will work and bootstrap modal wont work giving me a bunch of errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: t(...).on is not a function(anonymous function) @ bootstrap-min.js:11(anonymous function) @ bootstrap-min.js:11
bootstrap-alert.js:97 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function(anonymous function) @ bootstrap-alert.js:97(anonymous function) @ bootstrap-alert.js:99
bootstrap-button.js:99 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function(anonymous function) @ bootstrap-button.js:99(anonymous function) @ bootstrap-button.js:105
bootstrap-carousel.js:192 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function(anonymous function) @ bootstrap-carousel.js:192(anonymous function) @ bootstrap-carousel.js:207
bootstrap-collapse.js:157 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function(anonymous function) @ bootstrap-collapse.js:157(anonymous function) @ bootstrap-collapse.js:167
bootstrap-dropdown.js:164 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function(anonymous function) @ bootstrap-dropdown.js:164(anonymous function) @ bootstrap-dropdown.js:169
bootstrap-modal.js:232 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function(anonymous function) @ bootstrap-modal.js:232(anonymous function) @ bootstrap-modal.js:247
bootstrap-scrollspy.js:155 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function(anonymous function) @ bootstrap-scrollspy.js:155(anonymous function) @ bootstrap-scrollspy.js:162
bootstrap-tab.js:139 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function(anonymous function) @ bootstrap-tab.js:139(anonymous function) @ bootstrap-tab.js:144
bootstrap-typeahead.js:329 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
  [1]: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
```

I believe i have put the files in the right order before the `</body>` tag in the footer. Here is the code:

```
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/setup/include/js/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/setup/include/js/jquery/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/setup/include/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-min.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/setup/include/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/setup/include/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/setup/include/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/setup/include/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/setup/include/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/setup/include/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/setup/include/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/setup/include/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/setup/include/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/setup/include/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/setup/include/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/setup/include/js/jquery/jquery-linedtextarea.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
      // Target all classed with ".lined"
      $(".lined").linedtextarea(
        {selectedLine: 0}
      );
      // Target a single one
      $("#mytextarea").linedtextarea();

    });
</script>
<script>
    jQuery(function(){
        $("#getValues").autocomplete("/sfs/getIdsServlet");
    });
</script>
```

Could anyone suggest what the problem could be please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on for a WEEK, i somewhere read that using jquery 1.7.2 solved the issue for someone and that is what helped me out too! Many other versions of jQuery i used were not able to solve it!